# Apache SSHD: allow only white-listed commands

Tags: java, apache, ssh, sshd

I've implemented an SFTP server with Apache SSHD. Now I've got a question: is it possible to filter remote commands, i.e. "ban" some of them? For instance, currently it's possible to run `chmod` command, but I want to prohibit this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your use case precisely, but that looks dangerous indeed. If you built an SFTP server, you could parse queries and allow only the FTP command.

you can find the list of those commands there https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_FTP_commands